# Script works from shell but not Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a script that fills in parameters for multiple spark-submit jobs. The jobs work when I copy and paste them into shell, but they fail when I put the string in backticks and execute it from within Ruby.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster \
  --num-executors 2 \
  --files ... \
  --class ... \
  -otherflags ...
```

Ruby returns

```
sh: 1: spark-submit: not found
```

even though `spark-submit` is in the system path. Even more confusing is that:

```
`spark-submit`
```

within Ruby seems to call the shell command correctly.

Comment: How do you run ruby? How exactly do you use backtick in your ruby script?

Comment: I take the template shell script, fill in variables, and then execute using `#{shell_script}`. I use whatever ruby is `which ruby` on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what's different when you are at the command-line in the shell, versus when code is running in Ruby.

The shell has `PATH` defined, which it walks looking for the command, hopefully eventually finding the desired one.

Ruby doesn't do that, and instead, you need to define the absolute path to the executable. There are various ways of doing it but the simplest is to use

```
where spark-submit
```

at the command-line, then copy/paste that into your Ruby script. Most likely you'll end up with something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/spark-submit
```

or

```
/path/to/rubys/gems/.../bin/spark-submit
```

---

> `spark-submit`
>
> within Ruby seems to call the shell command correctly.

Ruby is trying to find the command in the current directory.